# Get separated string with a comma from a table

Tags: python, split, mysql-python

I trying to get separate strings from a column in a table. If I output them without anything they are looking like this:

```
('https://google.com',)
('http://example.com',)
('http://example.com,http://google.cpm',)
('http://example.com, http://google.cpm',)
('google.com, example.cpm',)
('google.com,example.com',)
('google.com, google.com',)
```

I want to check all off them with a function, if they are online or offline.
Here is my current script:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  database="python1"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT test1 FROM test2")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    x = .split(",")
    return x
    print(x)
```

I dont know how to fix this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write a function that returns the parts of the names as individual items, you can do that:

```
def getUrls(mydb):
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute( "SELECT test1 FROM test2" )
    for row in mycursor.fetchAll():
        for part in row[0].split(','):
            yield part
```